# UICollectionView - Select all cells doesn't update properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a button which selects all cells in the collectionview. Once clicked, the button function changes so that all cells will be de-selected upon pressing it again.

So far so good.. But
1) When you select all cells with the button, scroll a bit down and to the top again
2) Then de-select all cells with the button, and select all cells with the button again
3) And start scrolling down, some cells (mostly 1-2 complete rows, later cells are fine again) are not properly updated, so they *don't* appear with the selected state which is a different background color. Seems like an issue with dequeueReusableCell, but I can't wrap my head around it..

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
    if cell.isSelected {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    if cell.viewWithTag(1) != nil {
        let cellTitle = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        cellTitle.text = String(indexPath.row)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        selectedCells.append(indexPath.row)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        selectedCells.removeObject(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

And the action method for handling button clicking

```
@IBAction func selectButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if isSelectAllActive {
        // Deselect all cells
        selectedCells.removeAll()

        for indexPath: IndexPath in collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems! {
            collectionView!.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            collectionView(collectionView!, didDeselectItemAt: indexPath)

            let cell: UICollectionViewCell
            cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCell", for: indexPath)
        }

        selectButton.title = "Select all"
        isSelectAllActive = false
    } else {
        // Select all cells
        for i in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            collectionView!.selectItem(at: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())
            collectionView(collectionView!, didSelectItemAt: IndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
        }

        selectedCells.removeAll()

        let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        for item in indexPaths {
            selectedCells.append(item.row)
        }
        selectedCells.sort{$0 < $1}

        selectButton.title = "Select none"
        isSelectAllActive = true
    }
}
```

And for completion the array extension for removing an object

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    mutating func removeObject(_ object : Iterator.Element) {
        if let index = self.index(of: object) {
            self.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Complete Xcode project can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uaj1asg43z7bl2a/SelectAllCells.zip
Used Xcode 9.0 beta 1, with iOS11 Simulator/iPhone SE

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It would be much simpler and more efficient to use a `Set<IndexPath>` to track selection rather than an array. How do you set the cell selection in `cellForItemAt:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a little confused because you are trying to keep track of cell selection state both in an array and in the cell itself.

I would just use a `Set<IndexPath>` as it is simpler and more efficient than an array.  You can then refer to this set when returning a cell in `cellForItemAt:` and you don't need to do anything in `willDisplay`.

When you select/deselect all you can just reload the whole collection view and when an individual cell is selected/deselected, just reload that cell.

```
@objcMembers
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var toolBar: UIToolbar?
    @IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    var selectedCells = Set<IndexPath>()
    var isSelectAllActive = false

    // MARK: - Classes
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Collection view
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func selectButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if isSelectAllActive {
            // Deselect all cells
            selectedCells.removeAll()

            selectButton.title = "Select all"
            isSelectAllActive = false
        } else {
            // Select all cells
            for i in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
                self.selectedCells.insert(IndexPath(item:i, section:0))
            }

            selectButton.title = "Select none"
            isSelectAllActive = true
        }
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 50
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell: UICollectionViewCell
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCell", for: indexPath)
        if self.selectedCells.contains(indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        if cell.viewWithTag(1) != nil {
            let cellTitle = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            cellTitle.text = String(indexPath.row)
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("\ndidSelectItemAt: \(indexPath.row)")
        if selectedCells.contains(indexPath) {
            selectedCells.remove(indexPath)
        } else {
            selectedCells.insert(indexPath)
        }
           self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

        print("selectedCells: \(selectedCells)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I adjusted the test project according to your inputs. Also moved handling of visual cell selection from "willDisplay()" to "cellForItemAt()". Selecting/De-selecting all cells with the button works fine.
But now I have the issue that once a single cell is selected, I can't de-select it anymore. The cell always stays visually selected and "didDeselectItemAt()" never gets called.
Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2y9difx6b3ozdvt/20170711_SelectAllCells.zip?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I have updated my answer.  When you have multiple selection enabled you won't get a call to `didDeselect`.  This method is only called when single selection is enabled and another cell is selected.  My updated code clears the selection state and just tracks "selection" through the `selectedCells` set.

Comment: Still not working. I select a single cell -> Cell gets highlighted green -> I select the same cell again (de-selecting it) -> Cell stays green and neither didSelect() nor didDeselect() gets called.
Is the code running correctly on your system? Please note I'm using Xcode 9 beta 1 with iOS11.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Yes, working for me on the same Xcode version.  Did you copy my updated `didSelect` code correctly?  The `self.collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)` is critical

Comment: Sorry for being troublesome. I copied your code as shown. Button functionality works fine, only de-selecting individual cells upon tapping doesn't work. I attached updated project and a short video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2tv6fkya5ph0qu3/20170711_2_SelectAllCells.zip
Thanks for your patience.

Comment: In your `cellForItemAt` you are setting `cell.isSelected = true` - you don't want this.  If a cell is selected it can't be selected again, so the tap has no effect.

Comment: Wow.. completely overlooked that one. Works perfectly now. Thank you so much for your efforts! Really appreciate it.